# How to configure multiproject build in Gradle to build in root project and build it separately?

Tags: java, android, gradle, build

I having a problem with configuring multiproject build in Gradle.

My project structure is:

```
├── Some-Java_project
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── one-java-suproject
│   │    └── build.gradle
│   └── second-android-subproject
│       └── build.gradle
├── settings.gradle
└── build.gradle
```

And in `settings.gradle` I have:

```
include ':Some-Java-Project'
include ':Some-Java-Project:one-java-subproject'
include ':Some-Java-Project:one-android-subprojects'
```

and main `gradle.build` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(path: ':Some-Java-Project:one-java-subproject', configuration: "android")
    compile project(path: ":Some-Java-Project:one-android-subprojects")

      ...
}
```

Under 
Some-Java-project I have dependency:

```
dependencies {
  ...
    //For Java EE
    compile project(path: ':Some-Java_project:one-java-suproject')

    //For android
    android project(path: ':Some-Java_project:one-java-suproject', configuration: 'android')
    android project(path: ':Some-Java_project:second-android-subproject')
...
}


subprojects.each { subproject -> evaluationDependsOn(subproject.path) }
jar.dependsOn subprojects.tasks["copyArtefacts"]
jar {
    baseName = 'someName'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'some-name'
    }
    subprojects.each { subproject ->
        from fileTree(dir: 'build/classes')
    }
}
```

In each of gradle file under: Some-Java-project
I have a task :

```
apply plugin: 'java'

...

//Copy build classes into project root build folder when assembling jar file
task copyArtefacts(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'compileJava') {
    from('build/classes/main/')
    into('../build/classes')
}
```

and in `gradle.build` : one-android-subprojects

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
...

//Copy build classes into project root build folder when assembling jar file
task copyArtefacts(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'build') {
    from('build/intermediates/classes/release/')
    into('../build/classes')
}

...
```

Main goal here is to build android and Java subproject as subproject of 
other project, get compiled classes and put them together into one jar file.
This jar should be used in root project.
For now configuration is working because I directly reference subproject (
**one-java-suproject** and **second-android-subproject**) as leafs of Some-Java_project in main root project. But the problem is that when I checkout Some-Java_project in other location I just cannot simply run
grade build because there is no settings file and Gradle cannot find proper projects and I would like to have possibility to build project inside root project and when source is checked out somewhere else as stand alone library.

If I add settings gradle under Some-Java-prjoect with configuration:

`settings.gradle`

```
include ':one-java-subproject'
include ':one-android-subprojects'
```

and change dependencies it works but I do not want to add this separately. It should work straight away when checkout out from repository.

Comment: unable to understand the problem.

Comment: @MustansarSaeed I would like to checkout subproject Some-Java_project
in other place that mine root project (move folders to other location) 
and have possibility to build it without adding any files, changing anything.

Comment: Not sure I follow. settings.gradle is not a required file. If you have a copy of the sub project alone, why are you not able to build using `gradle build` from the directory containing gradle.build?

Comment: Firstly @RaGe [settings.gradle] is not needed in single project build. My submodule contains another two subproject. Secondly I cannot remove [settings.gradle] from root project. It already existing (in production) project which cannot be modified like that. It will destroy build logic there.